# To much logic in a Laravel subquery

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel project that has appointments.
At some point I want to filter the appointments based on the distance to a user, For example I would use the following query:

```
Appointment::withinRange()->get();
```

But the logic would look like this:

```
public function scopeWithinRange($query)
{
    return $query->with('patient', function($p) {
        $coordinate = new Coordinate([$patient->lat, $patient->lng]);
        $otherCoordinate = new Coordinate([$query->user->lat, $query->user->lng]);
        $distance = $coordinate->distanceTo($otherCoordinate);
        ...
    });
}
```

> This is too much logic, how would I go about reducing this logic?

All ideas are welcome! Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you're question is.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of distance queries using Laravel. Check laravel.io or laracasts for a plethora of questions/answers on this. And yes, you will always have a reasonably large query if you want to do this.

Comment: This seems like the exact reason for query scope doesn't it? To hide away more complex queries?

Comment: You could move the `distanceTo()` into a stored procedure on the server and then modify `$query` so that it calls it and also sorts in `ASC` order